# Load the first of several files

Tags: python

I have various files that I would like to load in this pattern:

```
file = None
if os.path.exists('2020-01-01.json'):
    json.loads(2020-01-01.json)
elif os.path.exists('2019-01-01.json'):
    json.loads('2019-01-01.json)
...etc...
```

I was thinking about doing a one-liner with `os.path.exists` but that just returns a boolean and not the filename/path. What would be the best way to accomplish the above on a long list of files?

Comment: Even assuming you meant `json.load()` instead of `json.loads()`, this won't work, because `json.load()` takes a _file object_, not a _filename_.

Comment: @JohnGordon eh that's all syntax, it's clear what they're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about use the negative logic?

```
file = None
filename = '2020-01-01.json'
while not os.path.exists(filename):
    ...some logic to generate the next filename...
    filename = new_filename
json.loads(filename)
```

Answer (score 1):

[`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) might help here.

```py
from pathlib import Path
from typing import List

root = Path.cwd()
jsonfiles: List[Path] = sorted(root.glob("*.json"), reverse=True)

jsonfile = next(reversed(jsonfiles), None)
if jsonfile is not None:
    with jsonfile.open(mode='r') as f:
        json.load(f)
```

Though the minimal change would be something like:

```py
all_possible_json_files = f"{year}-01-01.json" for year in range(2020, 2000, -1)
for json_file in all_possible_json_files:
    try:
        with open(json_file) as f:
            json.load(f)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the filenames into a list, then iterate over the list:

```
filenames = [
    '2020-01-01.json',
    '2019-01-01.json',
    # etc.
]

for filename in filenames:
    if os.path.exists(filename):
        with open(filename) as f:
            json.load(f)
        # we found a file, so stop looping
        break
```